# How to pass databinding object of any activity or fragment to a method parameter without needing to cast?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, data-binding

Lets suppose I want to add a toolbar shadow effect, for that I have created a toolbarShadowEffect method being used within the activity, but this is the type of method that can be used anywhere, so it would be better for me to add this method on my baseActivity class but then the issue of databinding comes in, every activity has a unique databinding object I don't see any superclass databinding object that I can place it on a method parameter, the only solution I figured out is by using the `ViewDataBinding` but for that I need to cast the specific binding in order to receive the view ids within the method making it redundant, my code is below.

```
public void methodA(ViewDataBinding dataBinding){

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        ((ActivityMainBinding)dataBinding).customToolbar.toolbarShadowEffectId.setElevation(8);
        ((ActivityMainBinding)dataBinding).customToolbar.toolbarShadowEffectId
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDBDBD"));
    }
}
```

Since I need to cast the specific databinding of an activity I cannot use this method on my super class for any activity or fragment binding, I want to achieve this mechanism without the casting any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**1** - You can declare an abstract method `getToolbar()` and implement only it in the child activities.

**2** - You can use `dataBinding.getRoot().findViewById(custom_toolbar)` if the toolbar always has same id. But then you probably can get by without data binding.